# Navbar with Bootstrap 5 and Hugo (static site generator)

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, sass, hugo

This is a question from a beginner. Sorry for that. I am using Bootstrap 5 and Hugo. I want to change the nav-item using Sass.

On image 1 you can see the finished result. The hover fills the whole space. If you move the mouse pointer over the link, the hover becomes active. Unfortunately I could not make a screenshot of this.

On image 2 you can see the button. The black lines left and right should go until the top and bottom of the navbar. Unfortunately it does not go to the upper and lower edge. The hover becomes active when the mouse pointer is moved over it. If the button is clicked, the active button does not become dark like in image 1.

[image: The result]

[image: Picture 2]

navbar.html

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-primary shadow-sm fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
            aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                {{ range .Site.Menus.main }}
                {{ if .HasChildren }}
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle{{ if $.HasMenuCurrent " main" . }} active{{ end }}" href="#" role="button"
                        data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                        {{ .Pre }}<span>{{ .Name }}</span>{{ .Post }}
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        {{ range .Children }}
                        {{ if eq .Params.divider true }}
                        <li>
                            <hr class="dropdown-divider">
                        </li>
                        {{ else }}
                        <li>
                            <a class="dropdown-item{{ if $.IsMenuCurrent " main" . }} active" aria-current="page{{ end }}"
                                href="{{ .URL }}">
                                {{ .Pre }}<span>{{ .Name }}</span>{{ .Post }}
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        {{ end }}
                        {{ end }}
                    </ul>
                </li>
                {{ else }}
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link{{ if $.IsMenuCurrent " main" . }} active" aria-current="page{{ end }}" href="{{ .URL }}">
                        {{ .Pre }}<span>{{ .Name }}</span>{{ .Post }}
                    </a>
                </li>
                {{ end }}
                {{ end }}
            </ul>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">{{.Site.Title }}<img src="/images/logo.jpg" class="logo"
                    alt="{{ .Site.Title }}"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

styles.scss

```
/* import the necessary Bootstrap files */
@import "bootstrap/functions";
@import "bootstrap/variables";

$font-family-sans-serif: Roboto, -apple-system, system-ui, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif;
$font-family-base: $font-family-sans-serif;

$box-shadow-sm: 1px 1px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
$navbar-nav-link-padding-x: 1rem;

.navbar .navbar-nav .nav-link {
    color: #ffffff;
    border-left: solid 1.5px #000;
}

.navbar .navbar-nav .nav-item:hover {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
}

.navbar .navbar-nav .nav-item:active {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
}

.nav-item:last-child {
    border-right: solid 1.5px #000;
}

a.navbar-brand {
    margin-right: 10.5rem;
    width: 300px;
    padding-right: 50px;
}

.logo {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: -17px;
    margin-left: 30px;
    height: 100px;
}


$theme-colors: (
    "light": #b2d7e8,
    "dark": #0d0b0d,
    "primary": #990033,
    "secondary": #42475f,
    "info": #68919d,
    "success": #559300,
    "warning": #ffb955,
    "danger": #ea0064,
);


@import "bootstrap/bootstrap";
```

javascript for the active state. The code doesn't work

```
// handle anchor links (onclick)
let anchorLinks = document.querySelectorAll('a[href^="#"]');
for (let item of anchorLinks) {
    item.addEventListener("click", e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        let hashVal = item.getAttribute("href");
        scrollToAnchor(hashVal);
    });
}
```